# Is this a power cable coming from utility line?

Tags: electrical

Slightly confused as to what this wire is. Is this power? This house was built in the 1950s and I believe had knob and tube wiring. However I noticed that I do have a service drop for electrical on my roof.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Generally power poles have a tier system.

(optional) Top top top = lightning arrestor cable (grounded) placed so lighting will hit it instead of the power lines

(optional) Top top = high voltage (note fat or stacked insulators) and often 2-wire, but can be 3-wire, and on a cross-bar.    You will often see them go to weird fixtures, such as the cutout switches on the 2nd pole.

Upper = 120/240V AC power distribution (3 wires) on short insulators usually on a crossbar.  *All the triplex service drops to houses will come off this.*

Middle = Telephone

Bottom = cable TV

On your photo, the standard telephone splice boxes can be seen on the middle tier.

Yours is going to the bottom tier, so it's cable TV.

Comment: As a former CATV technician, I can confirm this answer. It's a poor installation, however. The self-supporting wire molded into the coaxial cable is secured to the house, but bending the coax over on itself and securing it in the manner displayed is less than optimum. The cable tie should be removed.

Comment: How do I remove this? Do I call cable company?

Answer (score 2):

That is a cable line so it would be your internet, phone and or TV or any combination of them.

The main power coming in to your house is the triplex (3 wires twisted together) that in the 3rd photo posted run up to the lower cross bar on the utility pole

Answer (score 1):

The twisted wires that are around the bolt are steel to support the electric cables . They are/should not be tied into any electric. Your house was built about 50 years too late for knob and tube ( in US).